# Solving the system $a^2(b+c)=2$, $b^2(c+a)=4$, $c^2(a+b)=10$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I need to solve this system:

$$a^2(b+c)=2, b^2(c+a)=4, c^2(a+b)=10$$ and indeed I have found a few solutions using a Wolfram Alpha. These are the given answers

[image]

But I can't figure how to find these solutions by myself. I have tried by the substitution method, hoping to find a simpler equation for one of the three unknowns, but I'm still running in circles.

Comment: Ummm.... why do you have to find these solutions by hand?  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: It seems to me that there is no real roots (in $\Bbb R$)

Comment: You can solve this using [Resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it's just for understanding.

Comment: @NN2 indeed, wolfram gives me several real solutions.

Comment: @Somos, I appreciate your suggestion! May you give me another reference for a more in-depth understanding in this topic, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can understand without doing the calculation by hand, of course.  You can understand division of two 100-digit numbers and let the computer do the work.  Anyway, you might look up Gröbner bases if you want to move forward:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis

Comment: @math_failure In fact, there is just 1 real solution  (the second one from WA). The others are imaginary solutions. For example, $\sqrt[3]{-1}$,$ \sqrt[3]{11-5\sqrt{5}}$ both are not real. And all other solution $(a,b,c)$ contain an imaginary number like that.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to solve the systems of
equations you are asking about. Here is a way using symmetric polynomials.

Given three variables, $\,a,b,c,\,$ the elementary
symmetric polynomials are

$$ e_1 := a+b+c,\quad e_2 :=ab+bc+ca,\quad e_3:=abc. $$

Define the three (assumed known) quantities
$$ x:= a^2(b+c),\quad y:=b^2(b+c),\quad z:=c^2(c+a).$$
Define the corresponding elementary symmetric polynomials
$$ E_1:=x+y+z,\quad E_2:=xy+yz+zx,\quad E_3:=xyz.$$
The two sets of symmetric polynomials satisfy
$$ E_1 \!=\! e_1e_2-3e_3,\,
E_2 \!=\! e_2^3+3e_3^2-2e_1e_2e_3,\\
E_3 \!=\! e_3^2(e_1e_2-e_3). $$

Use this set of equations to get
$$ e_1e_2 = E_1+3e_3 = E_3/e_3^2 + e_3. $$
This implies that $\,e_3\,$ is a solution of
the cubic equation
$$ E_3 = 2e_3^3 + E_1e_3^2. $$
Next, the definition of $\,E_2\,$ gives a cubic equation
for $\,e_2.\,$ Thus there are $\,3^2=9\,$ solutions for
$\,e_2,e_3.\,$ Finally, find $\,a,b,c\,$ by
$$ a = \frac{x+e_3}{e_2}, \quad
b = \frac{y+e_3}{e_2},\quad
c = \frac{z+e_3}{e_2}. $$

---

NOTE: In your particular case of $\,(x,y,z)=(2,4,10),\,$
there are three real solutions and six complex ones.
The real solutions (to five decimal places) are:
$$ (a,b,c) = (0.76314,1.14471,2.28943), $$
$$ (a,b,c) = (-0.56497,0.91415,5.35154), $$
$$ (a,b,c) = (2.80967,1.73647,-1.48313). $$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is so clear and well explained. I appreciate your time for explaining me this procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The Gröbner bases for this set of equations are:

$$\{(-12 + c^3) (-500 - 150 c^3 + c^6), 1400 b + 1100 c - 162 c^4 + c^7, 
 1050 a + 1450 c - 162 c^4 + c^7 \}$$

Solving for $c^3$ in the first basis function by standard techniques (trivial and quadratic equation) give:

$$c = \left\{\left\{c\to -\sqrt[3]{-3} 2^{2/3}\right\},\left\{c\to (-2)^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{3}\right\},\left\{c\to 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3}\right\},\left\{c\to \sqrt[3]{-5
   \left(7 \sqrt{5}-15\right)}\right\},\left\{c\to -\sqrt[3]{5 \left(7
   \sqrt{5}-15\right)}\right\},\left\{c\to -(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{5 \left(7
   \sqrt{5}-15\right)}\right\},\left\{c\to -\sqrt[3]{-5 \left(15+7
   \sqrt{5}\right)}\right\},\left\{c\to \sqrt[3]{5 \left(15+7
   \sqrt{5}\right)}\right\},\left\{c\to (-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{5 \left(15+7
   \sqrt{5}\right)}\right\}\right\}$$

Then you substitute these into the second Gröbner basis function to find $b$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is illuminating. I'm eager to learn more about  Gröbner bases. May you give me a good to reference to begin, please?

Comment: @math_failure.  I think you should be able to find a good reference on your own.  Take charge of your education!

Answer (score 1):

**Some observations**

Considering the identities below:

\begin{align}
  E &=(b+c)(c+a)(a+b) \tag{1} \\
  E &= a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b)+2abc \tag{2}
\end{align}

From $(1)$,

$$a^2b^2c^2E=80 \tag{3}$$

From $(2)$,

$$E=16+2abc \tag{4}$$

Let $t=abc$ and combining $(3)$ and $(4)$,

$$t^2(16+2t)=80 \tag{$\star$}$$
$$ \implies t=2,-5\pm \sqrt{5}$$

Now let $(x,y,z)=(bc,ca,ab)$, we have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & t & t \\
  t & -4 & t \\
  t & t & -10
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z
\end{pmatrix}
=0$$

The matrix is singular when

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & t & t \\
  t & -4 & t \\
  t & t & -10
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Interestingly, it is equivalent to $(\star)$.

The table below shows the eigenvectors correspoinding to zero-eigenvalue for specific $t$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  t & 2 & -5+\sqrt{5} & -5-\sqrt{5} \\ \hline
  \vec{v} &
  \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix} &
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8} (\sqrt{5}+1)^3 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} (\sqrt{5}+1)^2 \\
    1
  \end{pmatrix} &
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{5}}{8} (\sqrt{5}-1)^3 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} (\sqrt{5}-1)^2 \\
    -1
  \end{pmatrix} \\ \hline
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\ b \\ c
  \end{pmatrix} &
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}} \\
    \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}} \\
    \sqrt[3]{12}
  \end{pmatrix} &
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -2^{-4/3} (\sqrt{5}-1)^{5/3} \\
    2^{-1/3} (\sqrt{5}-1)^{2/3} \\
    \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} (\sqrt{5}+1)^{4/3}
  \end{pmatrix} &
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2^{-4/3} (\sqrt{5}+1)^{5/3} \\
    2^{-1/3} (\sqrt{5}+1)^{2/3} \\
    -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} (\sqrt{5}-1)^{4/3}
  \end{pmatrix} \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you very much! Quite impressive use of eigenvalues. Indeed,  a clever solution that my students can understand with linear algebra. I'm sincerely grateful for the time you spend explaining to me the solution.